# Call works in Postman but not in C#

Tags: c#, postman, restsharp

I am trying to make a call to below URL and it works just fine in Browser (Chrome) and also in Postman, but for some reason, it doesn't work in C#.

**Working in browser:**
http://AJWKBLWT47VR26QWPNFCPJLXC6217F6F@presta.craftingcrow.com/api/categories

**Working in Postman:**
http://AJWKBLWT47VR26QWPNFCPJLXC6217F6F@presta.craftingcrow.com/api/categories

**Not working in C# (RestSharp):**

```
var client = new RestClient("http://AJWKBLWT47VR26QWPNFCPJLXC6217F6F@presta.craftingcrow.com/api/categories"); 
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("User-Agent", @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

**Response:**
401 Unauthorized
[image]

P.S. If I remove **User-Agent** it still doesn't work. Why am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, based on the content it looks like you're getting a `401` error, so you probably need to send an `Authorization` header of some sort. How are you authenticating that endpoint in postman / the browser?

Comment: As @Joshua pointed out, missing Auth.  The information is tacked onto the url.    Move it to an authorization header:  request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("AJWKBLWT47VR26QWPNFCPJLXC6217F6F:"));

Comment: Thank you both! This is exactly what I was missing. I am not sure why it is working in Postman without any authorization header. After adding this code snippet it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Joshua & Vhoang!

It's working after I changed code to below:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://presta.craftingcrow.com/api/categories"); 
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("AJWKBLWT47VR26QWPNFCPJLXC6217F6F:"));
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

There was no need to add user-agent or include key in the hostname (URL)

Answer (score 1):

Go into postman and, after you submit the request, check the Headers tab for anything that may have been added in the "temporary headers" section if you haven't specified anything in the Authorization tab.

In this example, I haven't called out an Authorization header but Postman is supplying one anyway:

[image]

Then add the missing relevant header(s) into your code. I like to click the "Code" button to the far right of the request. It gives you a dropdown so that you can choose pre-generated code in your desired language. This will most likely give you a reproducible example.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`RestClient` constructor accepts URI that doesn't include `userinfo`

```
          userinfo       host      port
          ┌──┴───┐ ┌──────┴──────┐ ┌┴┐
  https://john.doe@www.example.com:123/forum/questions/?tag=networking&order=newest#top
  └─┬─┘   └───────────┬──────────────┘└───────┬───────┘ └───────────┬─────────────┘ └┬┘
  scheme          authority                  path                 query           fragment
```

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier

In order to make it work with RestSharp, we'll need to do a little bit of extra work here:

```cs
// Old:
// var client = new RestClient("http://AJWKBLWT47VR26QWPNFCPJLXC6217F6F@presta.craftingcrow.com/api/categories"); 

// New:
var client = new RestClient("http://presta.craftingcrow.com/api/categories")
{
    Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("AJWKBLWT47VR26QWPNFCPJLXC6217F6F", "")
};
```