# Getting StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers error when Calling a API via code

Tags: c#, rest, webapi

I try to call an external api, when I am using the Postman, it is working and returning value as follows:

Post to URL:  https://test.com/api/v1/users/check

Data Raw Jason to post:

```
 { 
  "access_token":"4444-EA444B6-2844C7-A09C-44B05CA78E42A3", 
  "email":"test@test.com", 
  "create_user": true, 
  "first_name": "test4", 
  "last_name": "test", 
  "phone": 3104054512 
  }
```

So this is working and returning me response model.

but when try this code to call the api:

**Controller:**

```
     [Route("CreateUser")]
    public Task<UserReturn> CreateUser([FromBody] User user)
    {

        return  homebirdRepository.CreateUser(user);
    }



 public async Task<UserReturn> CreateUser(User userCheck)
    {
        using (GetWSObject<UserReturn> addObjectInt = new GetWSObject<UserReturn>())
        {
            return await addObjectInt.PostWSObjectModel("api/v1/users/check", userCheck, "API_URI");
        }
    }






    public async Task<T> PostWSObjectModel(string uriActionString, Object model, string apiKey)
    {
        T returnValue = default(T);

        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[apiKey]);
                var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uriActionString, content);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


                var test = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


                returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(((HttpResponseMessage)response).Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw (e);
        }
    }
```

This code is returning me this error:

```
   StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: 
 System.Net.Http.StreamContent, 
   Headers:
  {
   Connection: keep-alive
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
 Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested- 
With
 Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
  Cache-Control: no-cache, private
 Date: Sat, 28 Dec 2019 00:00:04 GMT
 Set-Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IlI2MUdzOFJmS0RcL1k1VmJCeTc4bk1nPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlZXNW11MGw2bXk0ajFEaTM2VnhmbUZjQnFzdnRDRHV5ejJMaDRqTVJYQm1yclNyUUkweDNRMUhpZDZwblpES1MiLCJtYWMiOiI0NmFiODA4YzEyNTkxZDllNDViNGUwOGIzYjY2ZWYxZGQwNzI1NmZmYzYxYTBkZGU0M2NmMDBlYzIzN2E3OTFjIn0%3D; expires=Sat, 28-Dec-2019 02:00:04 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
}}
```

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. You have likely set an extra header(s) in Postman that you aren't setting in .NET, which is why your request is being rejected in the latter case. Use Fiddler to monitor the two different requests and you will immediately be able to see what's different between them, which will tell you what you're doing in Postman that you also need to do in your code.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a header, cookie, etc. that is not set in C# which is set in Postman. There are several ways you can determine which properties are being set in Postman. I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59312199). Fiddler or some other separate tool shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you must add the Authorization header, this one is added and calculated by postman, you can copy/post. the following if you are using a Basic authentication.

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "value to copy from postman");