# API call (httpclient / IHttpClientFactory ) with API_Key Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, httpclient, ihttpclientfactory

I want to call third party API with API_Key Authorization.
Please find  my code and it return "StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1"
I tried to add API Key by 2 approach and both gives above response. Please advise.

```
var data = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DocumentRequest), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
{
    return true;
};

    using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(apiKey, apiKeyValue);
    
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(apiKey, apiKeyValue);
        
    var response = await client
    .PostAsync(apiEndPoint, data, cancellationToken)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
    
    var errorResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Request rejected by validation process " + errorResponse);
        throw new Exception($"{nameof(response.StatusCode)}:{response.StatusCode}:{errorResponse}, Request rejected.");
    }
    var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    return responseBody;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where you're using `IHttpClientFactory`. The idea behind that interface is that you setup commonly used headers and things precisely so that you don't have to set them on each instance of `IHttpClient` as you are in this code. See [Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Question is missing definitions of the variables that you use to add the API key header. There's no way to tell from the question whether the approach you are taking is what the service expects.

Comment: The API work with postman where Authorization Type is "API Key" and given Key and value .  Here I am not used IHttpClientFactory but you can explain how to do with this or httpclient.

Comment: From the error message, you can try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59507134/getting-statuscode-401-reasonphrase-unauthorized-version-1-1-content-sy)