# HttpClient PostAsync throws exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I m trying to fetch an api.When I try to fetch it with postman its working perfectly and I can see response of request but with PostAsync I cant fetch it and throw exception like below.Do you have any suggestion for this?

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
var data = new DataCollectorApiParams(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-20));
try
{
    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsync("http://localhost:8080/api/stock",
        new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

I get the following error:

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error)
>          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
>          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
>          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
>          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: this doesn't look like an issue with your http call (or you would get a response with a bad response code). It seems to be the connection to "http://localhost:8080". what kind of project are you running this code on?

Comment: "localhost:8080" is a docker container that include  rest api that written with .net core

Comment: and where are you running your httpclient code from?

Comment: Httpclient code is not in docker container.its a console application in windows 10 OS

Comment: @YusufKayikci When you ran the container, `docker run ...` have you published the port in which your service run to port 8080 on the Docker host. This is done by passing the flag value `-p 8080:80` ? For more on the latter, please have a look at https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/. If you haven't publish the port, then the service that run inside the container is not accessible from the host machine, by using the `locahost:8080`.

Comment: Yes i did it as i said its working with postman and i can get response successfully but httpclient throw exception as above.

Comment: i get postman works. for some reason, your console app can't connect to the endpoint. Try a simple `await _client.GetAsync(""http://localhost:8080")` and check if it throws errors

Comment: do you have logs for the server-side? can you check if your call reaches the server

Comment: Can you use Fiddler or view the request that Postman is generating in order to see if there's anything slightly different you may be missing? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59312022/call-works-in-postman-but-not-in-c-sharp/59312199#59312199

Comment: var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8080/api/stock");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\t\"StartDate\" : \"2019-9-30\",\n\t\"EndDate\" : \"2019-12-20\"\n}",  ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

Comment: That was a good idea to see generated request in Postman  . client.TimeOut = -1 . it was a good point to solve this problem Thanks @djsoteric

Comment: Using docker containers I've never had much success with localhost. Try `0.0.0.0:8080` instead, usually that works